# azure app service, container without exposed port shutdown after a while

Tags: azure, azure-devops, containers

I created a Celery image that connects to my Azure Redis cache. I deployed it on Azure App service container. It works, however the container is shut down after a period of time because Azure cannot ping the port 80. Because it's a Celery server which only communicates with my Redis broker, therefore I do not open any port. How can I handle this ?
Please note that the option "Always On" is activated.

The error message is:

```
2022-04-11T13:18:40.687Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 82.9096881 sec
2022-04-11T13:19:12.920Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 115.1424324 sec
2022-04-11T13:19:28.044Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 130.2660597 sec
2022-04-11T13:19:43.143Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 145.3659352 sec
2022-04-11T13:20:14.089Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 176.3117059 sec
2022-04-11T13:20:29.328Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 191.5505154 sec
2022-04-11T13:21:03.104Z INFO - Waiting for response to warmup request for container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394. Elapsed time = 225.3264671 sec
2022-04-11T13:21:08.172Z ERROR - Container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394 for site lucius-jobs-demo did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.3948725 sec
2022-04-11T13:21:08.176Z ERROR - Container lucius-jobs-demo_0_195f1394 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-04-11T13:21:08.183Z INFO - Stopping site lucius-jobs-demo because it failed during startup.
```

Answer (score 1):

I did open the port and create a function to answer the ping but obviously it's not the right solution

Comment: I was thinking to it but it's overkill. I hope there is an other solutions.